# Algorithm for counting common group memberships with big data

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, postgresql, bigdata

I need to write a program that counts the number of times two users are in the same group. The users are given by username and groups by id.
For example, with the input (stored in a text-file):

```
john 32
john 21
jim 21
jim 32
bob 32
```

I want the result:

```
john-jim 2 
john-bob 1
jim-bob 1
```

This sounds trivial. But the problem is: I have 1,8 million groups and 300,000 users. And a lot of memberships (I'm expecting at least an average of 50 per user, possibly much more). This means a HUGE amount of data and processing.

I've written 5 different programs doing this, none of which has been able to cut the amount of data:  It was too slow as an PostgreSQL query. Too memory consuming running in a Map in Java working memory (first heap space, after optimization I got the rare "GC overhead limit exceeded"). Too slow to write continuously to database from Java (even when optimized using batch-queries). Growing increasingly desperate, I've tried some more exotic things, like writing all the pairs to an array, then sorting them (O(n log (n))) and then counting them peu à peu. But it was still way too much data to store in memory.

Any ideas on an algorithm for doing this? Or is it impossible?

Comment: And you have `text` as user name there? Not an `integer`, like `user_id`? Also, `(grp, usr)` is unique, right? And your version of Postgres?

Comment: I think there are three options. 1) Add more memory to your computer. 2) Cut the data in pieces. 3) Use parellel computing where multiple computers are calculating part of the data.

Comment: Yeah, I have the username as text. I've made (grp, usr) unique. Postgres version is 8.4.0. Getting the user_id would require merging with another table, which would be too time consuming.
But I've managed to write all co-group pairs non-uniquely to a text file. It's 50 GB. I'm currently sorting it with Linux sort command. I'm thinking that from here, I could write a program that reads the text file peu à peu, counts the number of occurrences for each nick combinations and saves them to another file without storing too much in memory. 
Do you see any obvious flaws with that?

Comment: BTW, it's unclear whether the result should be sorted in any particular order. Makes quite a difference with a huge number of rows ...

Comment: Thanks everyone for excellent answers! The shitty solution I was doing ended up actually producing the results I wanted, after a couple of days of processing. The resulting file is 1.5 billion lines long, and around 40GB. As @ErwinBrandstetter predicted, this is a mess to work with, and I'll probably end up making a smaller version - next time using the queries kindly provided. 
(This is my first question - and I must say I'm really amazed by all the great replies! Thanks!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An RDBMS is specialized in operations like sorting. Doing this outside the DB will hardly ever come even close in performance. Do it with SQL!

This would do the job (simplified in update):

```sql
SELECT t1.usr || '-' || t2.usr, count(*) AS ct
FROM   usr_grp t1
JOIN   usr_grp t2 USING (grp_id) 
WHERE  t2.usr > t1.usr   -- prevent dupes and get sorted pair
GROUP  BY t1.usr, t2.usr;
```

Depending on how many overlaps you have, this potentially produces a HUGE amount of rows, as you said. So this is never going to be fast.

*Raises the question*: What's the purpose of producing millions of rows that nobody can process? Are you sure, the operation makes sense to begin with?

To make it *faster*, you could ..

- **Upgrade!** [PostgreSQL 8.4 is rather outdated by now](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). In particular, PostgreSQL 9.2 had its focus on big data. You can expect *much* better performance for a job like this.
  And *nobody* should be running 8.4.0. For security reasons alone, but you are missing out on lot of bug-fixes, too. The current point-release is 8.4.17. I quote the linked web-site:

> *We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor
>   release for whatever major version is in use.*

- use an **`integer`** as surrogate key for users, so you deal with integers only in `usr_grp`. Makes table and indexes smaller and processing faster. If the n:m table (`usr_grp`) has a much bigger cardinality than the table `usr`, this should be faster, even if it means additional joins.

```sql
SELECT u1.usr  || '-' || u2.usr, count(*) AS ct
FROM   usr_grp t1
JOIN   usr_grp t2 USING (grp_id) 
JOIN   usr u1 ON t1.usr_id = u1.usr_id
JOIN   usr u2 ON t2.usr_id = u2.usr_id
WHERE  t2.usr_id > t1.usr_id
GROUP  BY u1.usr_id, u2.usr_id;
```

- Create a **multi-column index** (if you don't have it yet).
  `grp_id` must come first. [Why does this matter?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

```sql
    CREATE INDEX usr_grp_gu_idx ON usr_grp(grp_id, usr_id);
```

- Put **a lot of RAM** into your machine and increase the settings for [`work_mem`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) and [`shared_buffers`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS).

#### Test case

I took the numbers [@OldCurmudgeon reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15831671/939860) for his test case and created a comparable test case in PostgreSQL.

[-> **SQLfiddle** demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0b72c/2)

~ **250 ms** in this public test database.
The result is not ordered (no `ORDER BY`) since this hasn't been specified.
As compared to **2.5 minutes**, [reported below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15831671/939860). Factor 600.

Comment: These benchmarks should be taken with a grain of salt as we only know the *average* group size and combinatorics are involved. In these tests all groups have ~8 members. Each will thus produce just C(8,2)=28 pairs. Suppose that, in the complete dataset, there is a single group with, let's say, 1000 members. That single group alone will produce ~500000 pairs. A single group with 10000 members (out of the 300k), do the math.... It it likely that real data are not uniformly distributed and there is a very large group lurking in there.

Comment: @jop: All true. The appended test case is really only to provide an order of magnitude in comparison to what OldCurmudgeon posted, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

How about letting your file system do it.

For each entry - open a file named for the group ID and append the new user's name. You will end up with one file per group.

You now have - for example:

```
Group-21.txt
 jim
 john

Group-32.txt
 bob
 jim
 john
```

Now run through all files, generating every user-name pair in it (I would sort the names and perform a standard combination process on them). For each pair, append a "1" to a file with a specific name.

You now have - for example:

```
User-jim-john.txt
 11

User-bob-jim.txt
 1

User-bob-john.txt
 1
```

You now have the pairs in file names and counts (in unary so all you really need is the file size in bytes) in the files.

Almost all of this could be done in parallel although phase 1 must complete before phase 2 begins. To improve speed - add cores - buy a faster disk. There is no memory limit, just disk.

**Added:** I've just run some simulation tests on this algorithm using just one thread

1800 groups, 300 users and 15000 memberships all randomly generated took about 2.5 minutes.
900 groups, 150 users and 7500 memberships took 54 seconds.

Comment: +1 for providing the results of your test case. Very useful! (Not for the proposed route to solve the problem). What software did you use for the test?

Comment: I too am a fan of shell hacks, but I don't think this very neat solution is going to work on this scale. We're looking at a directory with potentially millions of files. Each will use at least 1 disk block (plus meta-data!) and you'd be doing random writes all over them. With the original dataset, it would most likely thrash, badly. And to make phase 1 parallel, you need to use locks. Otherwise, processes opening and appending concurrently to the same file will overwrite each other.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I wrote a test suite in Java. I could post it if interested.

Comment: @jop - We can mitigate the FileSystem overload. We can place files in subdirectories etc - that is not a problem. File locking should also not be a problem as writes should be well distributed and lock contention should be comparatively rare. This may not be a "best" solution but it will work anywhere and it will terminate (given sufficient parallelization) in a similar time to the MapReduce solution.

Comment: @jop - My experiments suggest that phase 1 is comparatively short compared to phase 2 - as I would expect. We are doing an O((n/2)^2) process on ever file generated in phase 1. The benefit from this approach is that it will use a consistent and predictable run time and will only fail if disk becomes full.

Comment: Fun solution! And with a slight feeling of being a hack, which I always like. But I think generating 1.5 billion files in the filesystem would have been somewhat unpractical compared to the database solution. And not sure my server sysadmin would approve.

Comment: (Also, if the time would be linear with the number of memberships, and 15.000 takes 2.5 minutes, it would have taken me almost half a year to process. And it seems like it's actually superlinear, so even worse.) :)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the solution, the complexity depends on the number of pairs generated, not necessarily on the number of groups or persons. For different group sizes:

- a group with 10 members produces C(10,2) = 45 pairs
- a group with 100 members produces C(100,2) = 4950 pairs
- a group with 1000 members, 499500 pairs...
- with 10000 members, a single group will produce close to 50 million pairs! A single group can thus out weight the entire cost of the rest of the computation.

So my first suggestion would be to weed out very large groups in the dataset. If you can't omit large groups, and find out that it is not going to fit in memory or it will take ages to plow through it with a single thread, you can use [Map-Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) to automatically parallelize the computation as follows. If you start with group memberships such as:

```
32 -> john, jim, bob
21 -> john, jim
```

you can use the map step to produce all pairs:

```
john-jim -> 32, john-bob -> 32, jim-bob -> 32
john-jim -> 21
```

These will get aggregated for you by name pair. Then in reduce, just count the occurrences of each key. This assumes that you have plenty of disk to store all pairs.